# create alias for database name within same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

We have three database on same server (dev, test and uat). I am using a fourth database to perform some operations. I have views and stored proc created which utilizes the dev db. When I want to promote the code, I need to change the db name in all views and stored proc. Is there a better way of doing this? We are constrained with single server for all three environment.

Thanks
shankara Narayanan

Comment: When I had a similar problem I created table aliases which i used in the views. I then just replaced the aliases to point to different databases. Worked fine but can be a lot of work if you have many tables.

Answer (score 0):

Always script everything. Then you have a nice .SQL file that you can manipulate in whatever way is necessary. I prefer to set the all up with DROP/CREATE pairs for every view, SP and function. If any of them need to change, i update the script and rerun the whole thing.

I usually use a separate script file for the tables.

Comment: That's what I do now..but still if I change something I have to modify three scripts.

Comment: Not three. Just one. If you want to run it against UAT, do a find/replace to update the DB name.